# Refreshing jtable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I've created a jtable which can load data from tables in the database, im trying to show all updated or new records captured with a refresh button. Im using java, swing and mysql as my database.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, with value for JTable hardcoded as local variable

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Since that will require a new query to the database, the easiest way is probably to use a `SwingWorker` to perform the query and construct a new `TableModel` in the background. Then you simply replace the `TableModel` of your `JTable` on the EDT

Answer (score 2):

- read Oracle tutorial [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- description about [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for updates to `JTable` on runtime
- all updates to the already visible GUI must be done on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), (in your case) could be invoked from [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), otherwise you'll an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and your GUI will be freeeze until [hard and long running Object from JDBC ended](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)